# Excel VBA Looping

Tags: excel, vba

Okay bear with me on this, I am pretty new to VBA in Excel. I have been trying to figure out how to loop in a time sheet I made for error checking for a few days now and I am just dumbfounded.

My time sheet looks like this
[image]

So I have been trying to get a loop to look for empty cells.

My range would be ("C4:I4") & I need to run this on 29 rows starting with C4.

- If a row has data in each cell in the range then I would like it to `GoTo 500`.
- If a row has data in any cells but all are not filled in I need it to display a `MsgBox` to tell the user what needs to be filled in.
- If an entire range in a row besides the first is empty then I need to `GoTo 500` to run the save file part of the code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have scoured through the forums and tried to get multiple looping examples to work for me but have been unable to do so.

```
Sub checkemptycells()

    Dim x As String

    Range("C1").Select
    If ActiveCell.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox "Pick Your Name"
        GoTo 1000
    End If

    Range("G1").Select
    If ActiveCell.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox "ENTER A DATE"
        GoTo 1000
    End If

    Range("C4").Select
    If ActiveCell.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox "Need Job#"
        GoTo 1000
    End If

    Range("D4").Select
    If ActiveCell.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox "need qty."
        GoTo 1000
    End If

    Range("E4").Select
    If ActiveCell.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox "Need Work Order!"
        GoTo 1000
    End If

    Range("F4").Select
    If ActiveCell.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox "Pick a Dept.!"
        GoTo 1000
    End If

    Range("G4:I4").Select
    If ActiveCell.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox "Fill Start & Stop times on this line"
        GoTo 1000
    End If

    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim MyDate As String
    Dim USER As String

    FilePath = "Z:\TIMESHEETS\"
    MyDate = Format(Now(), "mm_dd_yyyy_")
    USER = (ActiveSheet.Range("  C1"))

    FileName = FilePath & MyDate & USER
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FileName, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    OpenAfterPublish = False
    xls.DisplayAlerts = False

1000
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
Dim i as Variant
Dim j as Variant

For i = 4 to 32
For j = 3 to 9

    If Cells(i,j).Value="" Then

    MsgBox "Missing value in Cell(" & i & " ," & j & ")."

    End If

Next j
Next i
```

Comment: It would probably make more sense to declare the range first and then use a single `For Each` loop instead of the nested loops.

Comment: @J_Lard I attempted to do Dim Rng as Range, Rng = Range("C4:I32"), then still found myself nesting loops.  This just seemed easier, in comparison.  If I was doing it wrong, that would also make sense why it was a pain to think through...

Comment: You could say `Set rng = Range("C4:I32")` then something like `For Each c in rng... If c.Value = ""...`. Either way should work though :)

Comment: Got'cha!  Thanks for the tip for next time... I'm still pretty new to looping, myself.  I have had lots of help to date to get to where I'm at.